# ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 0)) while a minimum of 2 is required by TSNE

Tags: machine-learning, doc2vec

I have this piece of code that I'm using in my doc2vec model

```
distance_matrix_doc = pairwise_distances(X_doc_subset, X_doc_subset, metric='cosine', n_jobs=-1)

tsne_doc = TSNE(metric="precomputed", n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=30, n_iter=500)

tsne_results_doc = tsne_doc.fit_transform(distance_matrix_doc)
```

after running it I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 0)) while a minimum of 2 is required by TSNE.
```

What might be the problem and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Getting that error suggests that your `distance_matrix_doc` is empty: it's got "0 samples", and "shape(0,0)". Which also implies that your `X_doc_subset` is empty. Of course, these steps can't do anything without input data.

So, look back at the prior code that was suppposed-to fill `X_doc_subset`, and check at each step, by observing the interim results, that it's doing what you intended before proceeding to these steps.

Comment: Ok Ihave these steps before the one I posted above

Comment: combined_defaulted_by_credit_type = credit_risk.groupby("credit_type").apply(lambda loans: ' '.join(loans['ID'].tolist()))

combined_defaulted_by_credit_type = pd.DataFrame(combined_defaulted_by_credit_type,columns=['all_credit_Ids'])
print(f'Number of credit types: {combined_defaulted_by_credit_type.shape[0]}')
combined_defaulted_by_credit_type.reset_index(inplace=True)
combined_defaulted_by_credit_type.credit_type = combined_defaulted_by_credit_type.credit_type.astype(str)

combined_defaulted_by_credit_type.head()

Comment: TRAIN_USER_MODEL = True   # True - create a new model, False - load a previosuly created model
MODEL_DIR = 'models'

if not os.path.exists(MODEL_DIR):
    os.makedirs(MODEL_DIR)

Comment: Lemme find a way to paste the whole code here

Comment: I reposted the Question. You can have a look at it in detail